# Storing a code block in PHP Storm to paste later

Tags: ide, macros, editor, phpstorm, hotkeys

I'm wondering if there is a way to store common blocks of code in **PHP Storm** so you can easily paste them later. I don't particularly want to use the extended Clipboard as that eventually goes away.

It would be great if I could store it and set a hot key so I can easily paste it.

Is this possible?

Comment: [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options which you can mix and match. In descending order of usefulness (IMHO):

- [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) are perhaps the most flexible, allowing operations on cursor, selection and more
- `Tools - Save file as template`
- [Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/scratches.html)
- Version control shelf (window Version Control, tab Local Changes, right click modified file, click Shelve)

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and see how I go :)